# How to access objects inside a List, saved in a Session. ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

So I have this code:

```
var list = new List<Carrito> { 
                new Carrito { ProductId = producto.ID , Cantidad = 1, PrecioUnitario = producto.Precio }
            };

            Session["list"] = list;

            return View();
```

Then I load the view but I don't know how to print the the content that is inside the session. Any ideas?

This is the code I use inside the view but doesn't work:

```
@foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<object>)Session["list"] )
{
  <p>@item.ProductId</p>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's as simple as reading back the value from your session varable and cast it to the original type, then do whatever you want

example:

```
@{
    if(Session["list"]!= null)
    {
    var listBackFromSession = (List<Carrito>)Session["list"];
    // do what you want
    }
 }
```

My recommendation is to use the more elegant way of ViewBag.

a quote from official asp.net mvc website about Viewbag:

> **New "ViewBag" Property**
>
> *MVC 2 controllers support a ViewData property that enables you to pass
>   data to a view template using a late-bound dictionary API. In MVC 3,
>   you can also use somewhat simpler syntax with the ViewBag property to
>   accomplish the same purpose. For example, instead of writing
>   ViewData["Message"]="text", you can write ViewBag.Message="text". You
>   do not need to define any strongly-typed classes to use the ViewBag
>   property. Because it is a dynamic property, you can instead just get
>   or set properties and it will resolve them dynamically at run time.
>   Internally, ViewBag properties are stored as name/value pairs in the
>   ViewData dictionary. (Note: in most pre-release versions of MVC 3, the
>   ViewBag property was named the ViewModel property.)*

Further more, This is a good article to read about the different ways you have in MVC in order to preserve data: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

example:

```
var list = new List<Carrito> { 
                new Carrito { ProductId = producto.ID , Cantidad = 1, PrecioUnitario = producto.Precio }
            };

// use ViewBag
ViewBag.myList = list;

then inside your view, read them back like this:

var myList = (List<Carrito>)ViewBag.myList;
// your code
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example did the trick. Does the second example (with ViewBag) saves the objects between pages like the Session?

Comment: Actually No, you have to reinitialize it again in order to be used in further round trips.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing MVC **fundamentally wrong**. In MVC, Views are there only to render a model. The logic of accessing that model should be implemented in controller, or in any other place, but not in the View itself.

Thus I recommend that you simply pass your **list** to the view, and make your view strongly-typed by including `@model List<Carrito>` at the top.